# string does not contain a definition for valueOf

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hello I have a Problem With my Code

string does not contain a definition for valueOf

Code In c#

```
        {
            public static String e(String str, int i5)
            {
                return String.valueOf(str.ToCharArray()[(int)(str.Length / i5)]);
            }
        }
```

Code In VB.NET

```
   Public Shared Function e(ByVal str As String, ByVal i5 As Integer) As String
        Return String.valueOf(str.ToCharArray()(CInt((str.Length / i5))))
    End Function
```

Here IS the Problem **String.valueOf**

Comment: Yes that statement is correct string does not have a definition of valueOf.

Comment: @Ralf how can i fix it?

Comment: I don't know. There is no valueof Method for string. So i can't even say what you do expect here what it does and where to look for an equivalent.

Comment: @mortadaali: Find out why it compiles in your C# code. It shouldn't. Java has `String.valueOf`, .NET doesn't.

Comment: @Heinzi i Translated this code from java its not my code i just want to use it in my project.

Comment: is what are you looking for?
string s ="xhhxzx";
 int i5 = 3;
 int res = s.ToCharArray().Length/i5;

Comment: @Ralf you mean my code is missing something?

Comment: No the framework is missing something. You can't just change java code into .Net Code. The java framework has different functionality then the .Net Framework. You need to find the fitting equivalent. Presummably there but definetly named differently.

Comment: @PowerMouse can you re type it as code i think it will be worked

Comment: @Ralf any other idea bro?

Comment: As i don't now what valueOf should be doing no.

Comment: If you're converting from another language and find something that is missing, first find out what the missing thing does in the source language, and then look for an equivalent in the destination language. Have you done that prior to asking this question?

Comment: *Code In c#* - no; that's not C# - the naming conventions are all wrong ;)

Comment: If the original code is Java then don't tell us it's C#. If you can't provide clear and accurate information when asking you're question, you're just making it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

is what you are expecting is to convert vb to c#?

```
void Main()
{
    string s ="xhhxzx";
    int i5 = 3;
    string res = e(s, i5);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    
}

 public static String e(String str, int i5)
            {
    return (str.Length / i5).ToString();
}
```

you can do in one line

```
public static String e(String str, int i5) => (str.Length / i5).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `valueOf` provides a string representation of some other kind of argument, like a `bool true` would become a string `"true"`. This code pulls a char out of the string at position `Length/i5`, converts it to a string and returns it

In C# you could do that with:

```
public static String E(string str, int i5)
{
    return str[str.Length/i5].ToString();
}
```

Or:

```
public static String E(string str, int i5) =>
  str[str.Length/i5].ToString();
```

In VB:

```
Public Shared Function E(str as String, i5 as Integer) As String
    Return str(str.Length/i5).ToString()
End Function
```